# XFCE Display manager hangs after applying settings

Tags: xfce, display-manager

I often have the problem that display-manager appears to hang the UI thread after applaying some settings (like disabling a screen) (see screenshot), and thus i cant click the "Keep settings" button during the countdown, so the settings get reset.  This happens in about 2/3 cases, so it takes a few tries to not hang. How do i fix this?

Version: 4.14

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: What drivers are you using? (what graphic card?)  Does that happen in other env? (KDE, gnome, icewm, etc.).  What happens if you do the changes via configuration files?